# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name source error: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a webform that performs both SQL insert and update. Each time I click update I get an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'id'
>
> Source error:
> Line 133:  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Here's my database

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movie] 
(
    [MovieId] INT         NOT NULL,
    [Title]   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Media]   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Price]   MONEY       NOT NULL,
    [Qtty]    INT         NOT NULL,
    [Genre]   VARCHAR(10) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MovieId] ASC) 
);
```

C# code:

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string id = txtMovId.Text;
        string title = txtTitle.Text;
        string media = txtMedia.Text;
        string price = txtPrice.Text;
        string qtty = txtQtty.Text;
        string genre = txtGenre.Text;

        string query = "UPDATE Movie SET id = @MovieId, title = @Title, media = @Media, price = @Price, qtty = @Qtty, genre = @Genre WHERE id = @MovieId";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieId", id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Media", media);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qtty", qtty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", genre);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                lblUpdateMsg.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        BindGrid();
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

Comment: Replace "Movie set id=@MovieId": by "Movie set MovieId=@MovieId"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. Even though you can update the primary key, it's not useful to update it to it's same value.
2. Your column name is `MovieId`, not `id`, so your `WHERE` clause is incorrect.

Use this code:

```
string query = "UPDATE Movie SET title = @Title, media = @Media, price = @Price, qtty = @Qtty, genre = @Genre WHERE MovieId = @MovieId";
```

Answer (score -1):

You are updating "Id" column which is not there in original table so replace your query as per below-

string query = "UPDATE Movie SET title = @Title, media = @Media, price = @Price, qtty = @Qtty, genre = @Genre WHERE MovieId = @MovieId";

Note:- you have passed correct parameter but it just a matter of replacing correct column name in SQL query.